# Access desktop application UI

Tags: user-interface, user-input, desktop-application, windows

This will be OS dependant so here goes:
Windows 7/8/10

I'd like to be able to access a desktop application UI from another application  (that I've written).

I'd like to be able to simply pass some mouse and keyboard inputs from my application to the external one.

Is this possible and if so, where do I start? Is there some Windows API that I can do this with?

I know I can use the Microsoft detours API to hook into Direct3D applications/games, but not sure about regular desktop applications.

Comment: [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx).

Comment: @IInspectable so I can automate any arbitrary external (3rd party/closed source) application?

Comment: That's not what you asked for. You asked specifically for *"regular desktop applications"*. And for regular desktop applications, UI Automation is your best bet. Some applications only have limited support (most notably those using the VCL). Applications that use standard Windows controls, or those based on the Qt-framework will expose the required interfaces. Use the [Inspect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318521.aspx) tool to find out, whether a particular application implements the required interfaces.

Comment: So what is a regular desktop application? Is it not something like excel or a game I've installed? If not, what do I call those non-regular applications? (So that I can rephrase my question )

Comment: By *regular desktop application* I assumed an application, that consumes regular input through mouse and keyboard messages (e.g. Excel). A game, on the other hand, responds to lower-level input services (e.g. DirectInput, or Raw Input). The latter cannot be automated through any automation interface, since it doesn't expose any generalized automation points.

Comment: Okay, so I'm looking to interact with regular apps like excel, photoshop, or some other application that runs on windows.